# How to install local tar file dependencies together with dependencies from CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

Let's assume there is a distribution "Example" that is packed in `example-1.0.tar.gz` which contains a `Makefile.PL` that points to all dependencies. After extracting, "Example" could be easily installed (including all its dependencies) by calling `cpanm .` if all its dependencies were available on CPAN.

How do I install a simialar file (let's call it `example-2.0.tar.gz`) if I am given a folder "deps" containing most of the distribution's dependencies

- dependency-1.tar.gz
- dependency-2.tar.gz
- ...
- dependency-N.tar.gz

where N is a huge number?

Further assumptions are:

- dependency-*tar.gz files have to be preferred over the available CPAN modules
- some dependencies are not available on CPAN but only in this "deps" folder
- the folder "deps" is incomplete and further dependencies have to be installed from CPAN.

Is there a simple way to install `example-2.0.tar.gz`?

I would like to know if there is some command line like `cpanm --use-local-deps=~/deps example-2.0.tar.gz` which does not need further workarounds.

Comment: Never used them, but maybe [`CPAN::Inject`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Inject) or [`CPAN::Mini::Inject`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini::Inject) could be useful.

Comment: I already tried CPAN::Mini(::Inject) before. The problem is, that things get pretty complex and I have to maintain a local CPAN mirror, which i kind of huge at the (currently I needed to download more than 3GB of distribution packages, that I don't need at the end). But thx anyway, for some readers this may be a good solution, too.

Comment: What about CPAN::Inject? As far as I can tell from the docs, that should work with your existing CPAN installation (no need to set up a local mirror).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this tool http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/CPANPLUS-0.9152/bin/cpan2dist . It lets you specify filters to define what modules are loaded locally and what is fetched from CPAN. It's part of the CPANPLUS module, which should cone with newer versions of Perl I think.